# Steps to integrate Python with Android

Tags: java, android, python, geolocation

I need to integrate my python code with my android application.
I am new to this type of integration so please tell me all the steps to do so.
I am currently creating an appliaction that just tells the geological information about the name of place you entered.
My python code takes the place name as input , traverses json and outputs the cordinates and other information.
Further I will develope it track a mobile phone through geolocation.
Now I have to integrate this with my Android app.
Please tell me steps so that I can understand it easily.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out [Jython](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/whatis.html)? It generally integrates Python and Java. You could actually do all of this in Java, if you wanted to do that as well.